# Is "use strict" necessary in ECMAScript 6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-harmony

I'm wondering when ECMAScript 6 comes, do we still need to put "use strict" in js codes?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately. Except in modules, where it is implied.

Comment: It's worth noting that modules is the expected way to work with big applications in ECMAScript 6, so there's a silver lining here.

Comment: @zhon, for modules, as noted (also, for classes). Not sure what you are asking specifically.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg, I think you said there are some case where "use strict" is implied and not needed. What are examples of this?

Comment: @zhon, I'm still confused what you are asking, since I thought I already answered that: inside modules and inside classes. If that does not answer your question, can you rephrase it?

Comment: @AndreasRossberg Thank you for clarifying. I was having trouble parsing the english. Classes and modules do not need "use strict".

Comment: Is this answer still true in 2019?

Comment: @Scribblemacher, yes, and it will never change, since JS cannot make backwards-incompatible changes -- they would break the web.